# Query in MySql from PHP, and JSON response for Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, highcharts

I have a issue whith a query on MySql table. I need a JSON response like this:

```
[{"data":[[1498902400000,1],[1400112000000,0],[1400112000000,0],...],"name":"1"},
{"data":[[1598902400000,0],[1500112000000,1],[1500112000000,0],...],"name":"2"},
{"data":[[1698902400000,0],[1600112000000,1],[1600112000000,1],...],"name":"3"}]
```

...but i recibe like this (all dates/int on "data:" identics):

```
[{"data":[[1498902400000,1],[1400112000000,0],[1400112000000,0],...],"name":"1"},
{"data":[[1498902400000,1],[1400112000000,0],[1400112000000,0],...],"name":"2"},
{"data":[[1498902400000,1],[1400112000000,0],[1400112000000,0],...],"name":"3"}]
```

...but only recibe the same "data:" (dates, int) for all names. I thing i have a malformed JSON estructure.
Thank you for help!

PHP File:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); 

///recupero nombre de Usuario de la sesion, fecha y idGrupo 
$sesionUser = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$sesionIdGrupo = $_GET['idGrupo'];
$sesionFechaActual = $_GET['fechaActual'];

///ARREGLO FECHA RECIBIDA PARA ADAPTARLA A FORMATO DE LA BD YY-MM-DD
$SesionFechaActualMes = explode("-", $sesionFechaActual);

mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion); 
$contador=1;
$arr = array();
$items2 = array();
$dia=1;
do {  
$idDispositivoWhile = $row_RecordsetTabla3['idDispositivo'];
while ($dia < 31) {
$query_RecordsetTabla = "SELECT fecha, count(estado) FROM registros WHERE estado = '2' AND idUsuario = 'xavi' AND idGrupo = '393' AND YEAR(fecha) = '$SesionFechaActualMes[1]' AND MONTH(fecha) = '$SesionFechaActualMes[0]' AND DAY(fecha) = '$dia' AND idDispositivo='$contador'";
$RecordsetTabla = mysql_query($query_RecordsetTabla, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla);
$totalRows_RecordsetTabla = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetTabla); 

$fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
$estadoCount = $row_RecordsetTabla['count(estado)'];
$arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
$arregloFecha2 = strtotime($arregloFecha) * 1000;
$contador++;
$arr = array($arregloFecha2, floatval($estadoCount));   
$items['data'][] = $arr;
}/////while que busca 31 fechas 
$items['name'] = $contador;
array_push($items2, $items);
} while ($contador < 3); /////while contador hasta 3
echo json_encode($items2);

////mysqlfreeresult
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla);
```

Note: The results is for fill a Highcharts chart.
Thanks!!!

I put a screen capture of table in Mysql...
[image]

Comment: In general, you need to have sorted data via x ascending.

Comment: Thanks for response Sebastian! ...¿only with sorting, the problem is solved? ...¿whith "oreder by ASC or DESC"?

Comment: i try order by, but not work :(

Comment: you need to order by x daettime, beacuse it seems that you sort it by primary key.

Comment: I tried to include the "order by fecha ASC", and the result changes. But can not get JSON expected in field "data:". I need this field change for each items in $contador (1,2,3 -----> should have dates / int different). Thanks also for the help Sebastian. Sorry, i´m newbei!

Comment: But what is incorrect in your JSON? You should also set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in the json_encode, to avoid return a strings, instead of numbers.

Comment: yes, the problem is the field "data:" on JSON. Ever returns at same dates for all elements $contador (realy is idDispositivo in table). I apreciate, and very thanks for your time!

Comment: in general you should avoid to use points with the same x, beacuse then you need to use scatter series type and lineWidth as 1.